# Find the position in text of ": - " or "? - " or ". - " or "; - " using a single code

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the position of the delimiter in a questions
A problem is that for different questions that delimiter may be different.
Is there a way to find the delimiter position regardless if it is different

```
a <- "S4a? How old are you? - 25-34years old."
b <- "S4a. How old are you. - 25-34years old."
c <- "S4a: How old are you: - 25-34years old."
d <- "S4a; How old are you; - 25-34years old."
```

I can run each of the below to find the position of each type of delimiter

```
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="\\? - ", a ))
unlist(gregexpr(pattern =". - ", b ))
unlist(gregexpr(pattern =": - ", c ))
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="; - ", d ))
```

They all return the same result

```
> unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="\\? - ", a ))
[1] 21
```

I've been trying this with little success as it just find everything within

```
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="\\?|\\.|; - ", a ))
```

Is there a way find any of the signs ?.;: and " - " in my search pattern.
Or does it need to be done with "? - " or ". - " or "; - " or "; - "

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do this: `unlist(gregexpr("\\W+\\s*-", a ))`

Comment: Thanks, interesting but will also it may find " -" if repeated in part of the answer. Will be useful for other circumstances though. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put chars that change in brackets like this:

```r
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="(\\?|\\.|;|:) - ", a ))
#21
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="(\\?|\\.|;|:) - ", b ))
#21
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="(\\?|\\.|;|:) - ", c ))
#21
unlist(gregexpr(pattern ="(\\?|\\.|;|:) - ", d ))
#21
```